# Help understanding basso continuo in Vivaldi's 'La Folia'

Tags: notation, performance-practice, figured-bass

This piece by Vivaldi is shown in the score to be notated for 3 voices. However in performances, there are 4 instruments played: 2 violins, cello and keyboard. The keyboard, along with playing the same line as the cello, includes extra notes which aren't notated.

The source of my confoundment is how it is known to play a 4th instrument, and how the keyboardist knows what chords to play, since there isn't notation for chords.

Comment: Related [question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/118097/2600).

Comment: Actually this question is answered there: basso continuo is frequently realized by two instruments, a melodic one, and chordal one.

Comment: @user1079505 FYI: Voted to leave open. The question here is that the score OP saw didn't indicate figured bass, so how did the harpsichordist know what to play?

Comment: @Aaron The score in the first video does say "basso continuo". I don't see OP referring to any other score.

Comment: @user1079505 Yes, it indicates basso continuo, but where are the figured bass indications? In the displayed score, b.c. is the cello; there is nothing to indicate chordal figures on a keyboard.

Comment: @Aaron ah, I get it now. I wonder, maybe the publisher/editor expected the performers to know folia chords and form? But it would be definitely nice to notate them at least for the main theme.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but do you actual know what "basso continuo" means? The basic definition will answer your question.

Comment: @user1079505 the edition in the first video edition looks rather like a homemade job in which someone, perhaps the creator of the video, transcribed a professional edition into notation software. The editor probably either did not understand the significance of the figures or simply couldn't be bothered to include them. (It's likely that they're not the same for every reiteration of the bass line.)

Comment: @Aaron "bc." means basso continuo regardless of whether there are figures present.

Comment: @phoog I think you figured it out, I would encourage you to write it as an answer.

Comment: @user1079505 I don't think it would add much to Aaron's answer, which basically implies that the performers must have been using a better edition than the one shown in the video even if it doesn't say as much explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original publication of the piece, the cello part is a "cello/continuo" part and includes figured bass.

The 'La Folia' sonata is number 12 in Vivaldi's Twelve Trio Sonatas, Op. 1 (SOURCE: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_Trio_Sonatas,_Op._1_(Vivaldi))). The score can be seen [on IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/12_Trio_Sonatas%2C_Op.1_(Vivaldi%2C_Antonio)). A portion is shown in the image below.

[image: Vivaldi Trio Sonata Op. 1, No. 12, mm. 1–8]

The video in the question displaying the score is a bit misleading in that the edition of the score shown does not include the figured bass that was part of the original.

Comment: Bar 6 looks somewhat overcrowded. Maybe it's just an inkblot?

Comment: @Tim Seems likely, since all the other bars, excepting the last, have the same rhythm.

Comment: @Tim It's a written-in C-sharp, isn't it?

Comment: @Richard - since the key's Dm, C# is always a possibility.  Looks more like C blob to me though.

Comment: @Tim Richard is correct.  It's a sharp sign.  Notice the larger distance between the stems of the first two notes in the bar as compared to the other measures.  You wouldn't expect the engravers to make extra room for an ink blot.  Also, listen to the piece.

Comment: In fact, the original part is not called "cello/continuo"; that's just the label it's given on IMSLP. The part itself is actually labeled "organo e violoncello" (organ and cello), but the title page indicates "violone e organo" ("violone" could designate double bass but here it probably just means "bass viol" sounding at 8' pitch). Of course, such designations didn't carry as much weight in those days as in later times, especially with regard to bass parts. There is certainly nothing wrong with playing the part on a harpsichord, a lute, a bassoon, or any combination of these.

Comment: @Tim the sharp sign in this engraving style is two pairs of fine diagonal lines.  You can see it more clearly at https://www.classicfm.com/discover-music/music-theory/renaissance-notation/ (ignore the cluelessness of the author).  The scan above seems to be at a somewhat low resolution, or the impression is a bit sloppy, or the paper too absorbent, or some combination of these, causing the sharp sign above m. 3 to look like an "X" and the one in m. 6 to blend into the staff lines.